# my android code does not connect to mysql in my computer ...iam running my app in emulator

Tags: android, mysql

i try so much times.....i cant connect to mysql database in my local host....when i run this coding in emulator-android

this is my java coding

```
package com.example.pravien.madattendence;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class Register1 extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
     try {
         TextView e=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
         e.setText("waiting");
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
         Connection con =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:8080/MadAttendence/", "root", "");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select name from colinfo where code='3106'");
        rs.next();
        String s = "" + rs.getString(1);
        e.setText(s);
    }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();};
    }
}
```

and this is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.pravien.madattendence.MainActivity2"
    android:background="#ff89ffd7"
   >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="REGISTER"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
   android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ID Number: "
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="400dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="collage code"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="400dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:text="3106"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="400dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next-->"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText4"
    android:background="#fffaff55" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

this my android manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pravien.madattendence" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >
    </activity>
  </application>
 </manifest>
```

this is my error show in log

```
 02-22 19:18:48.140    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence      W/System.err﹕ com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:  Communications link failure
02-22 19:18:48.140    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ [ 02-22 19:18:48.140  1135: 1135 W/System.err ]
  Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
02-22 19:18:48.150    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
02-22 19:18:48.150    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
02-22 19:18:48.158    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
02-22 19:18:48.159    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
02-22 19:18:48.159    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2104)
02-22 19:18:48.159    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:729)
02-22 19:18:48.159    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
02-22 19:18:48.159    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
02-22 19:18:48.159    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
02-22 19:18:48.159    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
02-22 19:18:48.160    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
02-22 19:18:48.160    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:283)
02-22 19:18:48.160    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
02-22 19:18:48.160    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
02-22 19:18:48.160    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.example.pravien.madattendence.Register1.onCreate(Register1.java:26)
02-22 19:18:48.175    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
02-22 19:18:48.176    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-22 19:18:48.176    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
02-22 19:18:48.176    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-22 19:18:48.176    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-22 19:18:48.176    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-22 19:18:48.176    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-22 19:18:48.177    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-22 19:18:48.177    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-22 19:18:48.177    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-22 19:18:48.177    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-22 19:18:48.177    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-22 19:18:48.192    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-22 19:18:48.196    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.SocketException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-22 19:18:48.197    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.unwrapExceptionToProperClassAndThrowIt(StandardSocketFactory.java:407)
02-22 19:18:48.198    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:268)
02-22 19:18:48.198    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:276)
02-22 19:18:48.198    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2027)
02-22 19:18:48.198    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/System.err﹕ ... 23 more
02-22 19:18:48.249    1135-1135/com.example.pravien.madattendence I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 120 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-22 19:18:48.662    1135-1155/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-22 19:18:48.662    1135-1155/com.example.pravien.madattendence W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6911a00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

pls help me.......

Comment: what's the stacktrace or error that you see? logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Your android emulator must be in the same I.P. class as your host. Try first access 10.0.2.2 (via ping or browser ) from emulator or, better, Second step: check your MySQL server permissions and grant access from other hosts (i.e. I.P. of your emulator).

Comment: hi ...can u elaborate pls..i couldnt get your answer

Comment: Check your MySQL permissions and grant access to other hosts. This is as is write. Can you ping your server (your localhost acts like a server) from emulator? This is as clear as I read. What else isn't clear?:) If those are good configured, there must be an error in your OpenGL renderer, and I think you should give a try on a real device, oe enable hardware emulation graphics for your emulator.

Comment: Are you running in Android Studio? If this is the case, change emulator or better create a virtual machine with android for testing. It so fun to have a 400% fast emulator than those provided with Studio

Comment: how to create virtual device?

Comment: can anyone give me a example for connecting to mysql please